# Search a string if it contains all of the substrings in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table(say table1) and has values in 'Name' field like: "My name is Vikash","My name is VGH","I have hjk"                                                                        and second table(say table2) has values in 'Name' field like:"My","name".And the result I need is   "My name is Vikash" and "My name is VGH"

I was trying to check for values from first table  if it contains all the values from second table by comparison but LIKE compares just one value.I need some multi value comparison function

```
Select  table1.Name from table1
where table1.Name Like(Select Name from Table2)
```

So, what happened is that the values from first table is checked if it contains all the values from second table.And if this contains all values from second table,I need that first table's value in result

Comment: LIKE does not work for comparing multiple values.I need any multi value comparator which I am unable to figure out.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: The second table does not contain only 2 values so please do not give some specific solution,I need a generic solution which compares all values in table2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try to count the matches using `CROSS APPLY`:

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (
   [name] nvarchar(max)
)
CREATE TABLE #Table2 (
   [name] nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO #Table1
   ([name])
VALUES
   ('My name is Vikash'),
   ('My name is VGH'),
   ('My name is VG3'),
   ('My name is VG4'),
   ('I have hjk')
INSERT INTO #Table2
   ([name])
VALUES
   ('My'),
   ('name'),
   ('VGH')
```

T-SQL (for partial match):

```
SELECT t1.[name]
FROM #Table1 t1
CROSS APPLY #Table2 t2
GROUP BY t1.[name]
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN (t1.[name] LIKE '%' + t2.[name] + '%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Output:

```
------------------
name
------------------
My name is VG3
My name is VG4
My name is VGH
My name is Vikash
```

T-SQL (for full match):

```
SELECT t1.[name]
FROM #Table1 t1
CROSS APPLY #Table2 t2
GROUP BY t1.[name]
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN (t1.[name] LIKE '%' + t2.[name] + '%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Table2)
```

Output:

```
------------------
name
------------------
My name is VGH
```

Comment: But the expected output is only: 'My name is VGH' because this contains 'My','name','GH' and others miss some of these

Comment: @VikashKumar OK, then the check in `HAVING` clause will be differenet. Check updated answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this? Select the distinct names from `tbl1`, and use a `JOIN` on `tbl2` using `LIKE`. We have to use `Distinct` as you'd otherwise get multiple results from the same values in `tbl1` (because the values `My` and `Name` are both matched).

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.name
FROM tbl1 t1
JOIN tbl2 t2
  ON t1.name LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.name, '%')
```

- See live fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b26d20/4

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.Name FROM table1 AS T1
INNER JOIN table2 AS T2
ON T1.Name LIKE CONCAT("%", T2.Name, "%");
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give your expected results I think. Please just ignore the RN column from your final result set.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.Name,A.RN 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    'A' AS COMMON,
    Name,
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name) RN
    FROM Table1
)A
INNER JOIN 
(   
    SELECT 
    'A' AS COMMON,
    Name 
    FROM table2
)B
ON A.Common = B.Common
WHERE CHARINDEX(B.Name,A.Name,0) > 0
```